# Google Chrome (Stable Version) on Mobile does not render colors accurately for videos (Android 12)

Tags: android, google-chrome, video, html5-video, chromium

Hopefully this message reaches someone and gets read as it is important to me

I have noticed that the mobile version of chrome does not render video colors accurately.

More specifically, blacks are being rendered it a slightly gray color (101010 in hexa) but only when the video is playing. If I take a screenshot the gray will show up as black.

I tried with different video encoding formats, framerates and bits per channel exports but I did not manage to solve this issue as the video is rendered in the same way.

Can you please help me with this?
Any questions you might have please let me know so we can reach a solution

My device is: Samsung galaxy 10e with android 12

Comment: If you think it's a bug then please report it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.